# New Folder button not working on some libraries from SP 2007 migration

Tags: document-library, migration, libraries

A vendor migrated over 175 libraries from SP2007 to SP 2010. On 15 of the libraries, the New Folder button is visible and looks active but generates an error instead. I know the workaround is to change the library view to Explorer but this is unfriendly to users. All the libraries in question have Links to Document or ".aspx" files stored in the library. Any help would be appreciated.

dwh

Comment: Just curious, if you create a new view on one of these lists from scratch, does the New button work from the new view?

Comment: possible that a non standard web template was used for the sites hosting the lists and libraries? You say a vendor migrated these so I assume this is a migration utility from metalogix or the like?

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling the New Folder command and then re-enabling it. It sounds to me like a specific list template type (possibly a derived one) didn't copy cleanly into the upgraded content database.

Clearing and re-setting the option *might* get this working again. There are similar issues with lists/libraries migrated from 2007 to 2010 losing their email-enabled functionality (while still showing it set up "correctly" in the options screen).

If that doesn't work, can you get the error out of ULS and post that here please?